# getting issue in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  addorRemCcToList(EmployeeList item) {
print('add or');
print(_ccToListSelected.length);
print(_tempccToListSelected.length);
if (_tempccToListSelected.contains(item)) {
  _tempccToListSelected.remove(item);
} else {
  _tempccToListSelected.add(item);
}
print(_tempccToListSelected.length);
print(_ccToListSelected.length);
notifyListeners();
```

}

so this is a method through which i'm adding or removing items in _tempccToListSelected this list but the issue is when i make changes in _tempccToListSelected this list this _ccToListSelected list get the same changes and i didn't event touched it
[as you can see in the picture it is the terminal showing the print result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XenZp.png)

Comment: Please for my convinent  , can you tell me the actual error because I am not getting what is the actual error and please copy paste your code  and avoid code images

Comment: hi Prime khan, Can you give more information regarding your problem

Comment: @Manishyadav  please check now

Comment: @AmitBahadur please check now

Comment: @PRIMEKHAN Sorry for late response but do these things 
_tempccToListSelected=_tempccToListSelected.remove(item)
_tempccToListSelected=_tempccToListSelected.add(item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly have a line like this:

```
_tempccToListSelected = _ccToListSelected;
```

or the opposite.

This line don't copy list into another one but make a pointer to the other list (like in numerous language).

If you want to copy (duplicate) the liste use spread operator:

```
_tempccToListSelected = [..._ccToListSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have code like this:

```
list1 = [];
list2 = list1;
```

this error is normal. You need give more information about this issue.